# Printing randomly to the screen in C

Tags: c

I am trying to print to the screen randomly in C. I am using random and time to generate random index and printing it but It definetely is not the way to do it. How do I print every element randomly to the screen in c?

Here is the code I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define leng 128 
#define arr 10 

int main(void) 
{
    char line[arr][leng];
    char fname[20];
    FILE *fptr = NULL; 
    int i = 0;
    int tot = 0;
    scanf("%s",fname);  

    fptr = fopen(fname, "r");
    while(fgets(line[i], leng, fptr)) 
    {
        line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    srand(time(0));
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", line[rand()%10]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My random text file has 6 lines of code.

Comment: you mean print each line once and only once?

Comment: @yano that is correct but in a random order

Comment: you'll need to keep track of what numbers have already been generated, and if you get a duplicate, generate another. Keep going until all in the set have been generated. Not very efficient. I think there are shuffling algorithms that could do a better job. But that aside, you could use an array of `bool`s, where the index into the array is the generated number. Set that to true for each generation, then check the whole array, when they're all true you're done.

Comment: be careful with `line[rand()%10]`. You say your file has 6 lines, then only `line[0]` thru `line[5]` are going to have valid data. Trying to print `line[6]` thru `line[9]` will invoke undefined behavior and probably print gibberish or segfault.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LEN 128 //Don't mind the capital, personal preference for defines
#define ARR 6 //Make this match the number of lines in your file

int main(void) 
{
    char line[ARR][LEN];
    char fname[20];

    int test[ARR] = {0}; //Added an array to test if index already created
    int ind[ARR] = {0}; //Array to store index created randomly
    int ind_done = 0; //Counter for index array

    FILE *fptr = NULL; 

    int i = 0;
    int tot = 0;
    scanf("%s",fname);  

    fptr = fopen(fname, "r");
    while(fgets(line[i], LEN, fptr)) 
    {
        line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }

    srand(time(0));

    for(int i = 0; i < ARR; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", line[rand()%ARR]);
    }

    //Keep creating indexes using rand till all unique indexes are created
    while (ind_done<ARR) {
        int i = rand()%ARR;
        if (test[i] == 0) {
            ind[ind_done] = i;
            ind_done++;
            test[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < ARR; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", line[ind[i]]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```